# syntax error near ");" en until()

Tags: perl

Tengo la siguiente parte del código y me dice que tengo un error de sintaxis cerca de ");" en la línea 1. No entiendo por qué si los paréntesis están bien cerrados. Gracias.

```perl
    until ($newbase eq substr($RNA,$position,1));
    substr($RNA,$position,1,$base);
    return $RNA;
```

Answer (score 0):

**until()** debe ser seguido de un par de llaves que encierren las sentencias a ejecutar hasta que se cumpla la expresión entre paréntesis.

Otra opción es que fuera un until() de fin de sentencia, pero no lo parece por el código que has puesto.

Más información en **perldoc perlsyn**